# Tomcat does not get enough memory

Tags: memory, java, thread

i'm trying to setup a jira instance on my vServer.

I've got min. 1 GB ram and max. 2 GB ram.
It was runing on my friends Server with only 512 MB ram.

The first error was:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

I fixed this with

```
ulimit -u 2048
```

After that, the error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurred dispatching signal SIGTERM to handler- the VM may need to
```

be forcibly terminated

occured.

My environment:

```
___ Environment _____________________________

 JIRA Build                                    : 5.0.6#733-sha1:f48fab7a0abaa0a316c14a3fc86cdf5a6805ba12
 Build Date                                    : Thu May 31 00:00:00 CEST 2012
 JIRA Installation Type                        : Standalone
 Application Server                            : Apache Tomcat/6.0.32 - Servlet API 2.5
 Java Version                                  : 1.7.0_05 - Oracle Corporation
 Current Working Directory                     : /tmp/atlassian-jira-5.0.6-standalone
 Maximum Allowable Memory                      : 742MB
 Total Memory                                  : 247MB
 Free Memory                                   : 210MB
 Used Memory                                   : 37MB
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You only have 742MB of total virtual memory. If your app requires at least 1G, you'll need to add more swap & configure the VM with a max that is lower than your total virtual memory.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 32bit-variant of `jdk`. If you do not need more than 3 GB of Java-accessible RAM the 64bit will only cause needless overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens often enough, you should increase the heap size using `-Xms512m -Xmx512m`  The default is only about 128MB, which for some systems is not enough.

You should also look to see if it is a memory leak in Jira.  Does it happen on a regular interval, for example, every 4-5 days?  Then you might want to look for patches to the servlet(s) and schedule occasional restarts.

Comment: i've got the server since tody. Jira has never run.
in my startup.sh of my tomcat 6:
    JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=128m
CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=128m

Comment: You'll need to look at the messages in `$CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out` for more information.  If `$CATALINA_BASE` is not set, then use `$CATALINA_HOME` instead.

Comment: the information where from catalina.out